# Can't use pixelRatio for canvas in react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've set up a 3D-model using react-three-fiber and want to make it responsive. The model gets really blurry on smaller screens so I want to use pixelRatio = {window.devicePixelRatio}. However, it can't find the prop pixelRatio and fails to compile. Does anyone know why this is?

The code:

```
<Canvas gl={{ antialias: true }} pixelRatio={window.devicePixelRatio}>
    <PerspectiveCamera>
      <axesHelper />
      <gridHelper />
      <OrbitControls
        target={[0, 0, 0]}
        enablePan={false}
        autoRotate
        maxDistance={1}
        minDistance={0.6}
      />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <Spotlight />
      <pointLight position={[0, 1, 2]} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Model />
      </Suspense>
    </PerspectiveCamera>
  </Canvas>
```

I simply get the message "Property 'pixelRatio' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'."

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. They changed it from pixelRatio to dpr recently. Works the same way as before.

Comment: dpr is dynamic pixel ratio, that and pixel ratio is not the same thing

Comment: Please make sure to mark this as the accepted answer. It's the only current solution I came across (aside from the official release log). @Epiczzor in the context of r3f, axwellfred is right. You can check out the r3f change log of v6.0.0 here: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/releases

Comment: Yeah he is right, but dynamic pixel ratio and pixel ratio is not the same thing, dynamic pixel ratio sets the pixel ratio based on device hardware capabilities whereas setPixelRatio force sets it. so its wrong to say that dpr and pixel ratio is the same thing

Answer (score 2):

to set pixel ratio, you can get "gl" from the useThree hook and go

```
gl.setPixelRatio(value)
```

if you want to do it on Canvas you have to define it in the gl prop for Canvas